# Porque mi programa no realiza la operación?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Tengo que realizar un programa por que calcule la raiz cuadrada por el metodo babilonico, lo realice con una interfaz en la cual pide el numero a calcular, la base y la altura pero al momento de dar en el botón de calcular no realiza la operación y me da como resultado 0 y ya no se que mas puedo realizar, el programa lo estoy realizando en la aplicación de Visual Studio de 2019, con la opción de Windows forms de C++.

De ante mano muchas gracias!!!

Este es el código de la clase operaciones.

```
#pragma once
ref class OPERACIONES
{

public:
    int x;
    int b;
    int h;
public: 
    float raiz(float, float, float);
    OPERACIONES(void)
    {

    }
};
float OPERACIONES::raiz(float x, float b, float h) {
    if (b - h > -0.0001 && b - h < 0.0001)
        return b;
    else
        return raiz(x, (b + h) / 2, (x / b));
};
```

Y este es el codigo de la interfaz.

```
#pragma once
#include "OPERACIONES.h"

namespace CppCLRWinformsProjekt {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Zusammenfassung für Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Konstruktorcode hier hinzufügen.
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Verwendete Ressourcen bereinigen.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label1;
protected:
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ TxtNumero;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ TxtBase;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ TxtAltura;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ BtnCalcular;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Erforderliche Designervariable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container^ components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
    /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->TxtNumero = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->TxtBase = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->TxtAltura = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->BtnCalcular = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 35);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(58, 17);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->label1->Text = L"Número";
        // 
        // TxtNumero
        // 
        this->TxtNumero->Location = System::Drawing::Point(78, 35);
        this->TxtNumero->Name = L"TxtNumero";
        this->TxtNumero->Size = System::Drawing::Size(178, 22);
        this->TxtNumero->TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this->label2->AutoSize = true;
        this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 84);
        this->label2->Name = L"label2";
        this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(40, 17);
        this->label2->TabIndex = 2;
        this->label2->Text = L"Base";
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this->label3->AutoSize = true;
        this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 133);
        this->label3->Name = L"label3";
        this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(45, 17);
        this->label3->TabIndex = 3;
        this->label3->Text = L"Altura";
        // 
        // TxtBase
        // 
        this->TxtBase->Location = System::Drawing::Point(78, 84);
        this->TxtBase->Name = L"TxtBase";
        this->TxtBase->Size = System::Drawing::Size(178, 22);
        this->TxtBase->TabIndex = 4;
        // 
        // TxtAltura
        // 
        this->TxtAltura->Location = System::Drawing::Point(78, 128);
        this->TxtAltura->Name = L"TxtAltura";
        this->TxtAltura->Size = System::Drawing::Size(178, 22);
        this->TxtAltura->TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // BtnCalcular
        // 
        this->BtnCalcular->Location = System::Drawing::Point(78, 201);
        this->BtnCalcular->Name = L"BtnCalcular";
        this->BtnCalcular->Size = System::Drawing::Size(165, 54);
        this->BtnCalcular->TabIndex = 6;
        this->BtnCalcular->Text = L"Calcular";
        this->BtnCalcular->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->BtnCalcular->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::BtnCalcular_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(396, 378);
        this->Controls->Add(this->BtnCalcular);
        this->Controls->Add(this->TxtAltura);
        this->Controls->Add(this->TxtBase);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->TxtNumero);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void BtnCalcular_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    OPERACIONES OP;
    OP.x - float::Parse(TxtNumero->Text);
    OP.b - float::Parse(TxtBase->Text);
    OP.h - float::Parse(TxtAltura->Text);
    MessageBox::Show("La raiz cuadrada del número es: \n" + OP.raiz(OP.x, OP.b, OP.h));
}
};
}
```

Comment: Interesantes los comentarios del código en alemán ;)